# Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.ts

Tags: angular, typescript

Am adding AdMob free to my ionic 4 project. 
I've created a normal service page as :

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  AdMobFree,
  AdMobFreeBannerConfig,
  AdMobFreeInterstitialConfig,
  AdMobFreeRewardVideoConfig
} from '@ionic-native/admob-free/ngx';
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';


@Injectable()
export class AdmobFreeService {
  constructor(
    public adMob: AdMobFree
) { }


  const bannerConfig: AdMobFreeBannerConfig = {
    // add your config here
    // for the sake of this example we will just use the test config
    isTesting: true,
    autoShow: true
   };
   this.adMob.banner.config(this.bannerConfig);

   this.adMob.banner.prepare()
     .then(() => {
       // banner Ad is ready
       // if we set autoShow to false, then we will need to call the show method here
     })
     .catch(e => console.log(e));

}
```

it gives me the error `Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.ts` with this line underlined :
`this.adMob.banner.config(this.bannerConfig);`
as I know, this is the way to import and call the plugin inside the app. need to know what causes the error !?

Comment: put that line in a function.

Comment: You're trying to declare a local const variable, and then run code, in the class itself. I guess it's supposed to be inside the constructor, so inside the curly braces, not outside.